# ios Single Sign on

Tags: ios, single-sign-on

How does one do SSO with ios. I know on Android you can use a content provider and access it from any app, but what do you do with IOS, is it actual sso still?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: no, but this may help http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/nathan-jones/single-sign-pattern-enterprise-ios-applications